# Which windows.h header defines NULL?

Tags: c

I have to write some Windows code, and I want to separate it from the Linux part as much as possible.

At one point I need to check for NULL in the Windows code, but I don't want to include `stdio.h` or `stdlib.h`.

I strongly suspect that NULL is defined somewhere in `windows.h`, but I can't find the page. I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccertenroll/about-null), which is interesting, but doesn't tell me what I want to know.

Comment: The article you linked is not talking about the NULL you are talking about, though. That's the NULL of ASN.1, which has nothing to do with C or the C preprocessor.

Comment: In general, the question is bizarre... The Windows API at large is talking about the C-language NULL, so in general you just use it including from stddef.h or any other header that provides it. It's not excluded that some Windows headers may provide it as well if not already defined to handle stranger scenarios, but that doesn't seem to be neither guaranteed nor necessary. Just use the standard C headers and be happy with it.

Comment: Do you know how you can be sure to get it? By including a header that is guaranteed to provide it. And do you know which header is guaranteed to include it? `<stddef.h>`

Comment: "I don't want to" isn't much of a rationale. Can you explain why?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question makes no sense

Comment: Re “I want to separate it from the Linux part as much as possible”: `<stddef.h>` is not a Linux part. It is part of the C programming language; it is specified by the C standard without any reference to Linux, Unix, or Windows. It is fundamental to C. Further, even if some Windows header defines `NULL`, it must be consistent with the definition provided by `<stddef.h>`, since many people include both `<stddef.h>` and Windows headers. There is no separation; many people use both, so including `<stddef.h>` must work with Windows headers. There is nothing to gain in what you are trying to do.

Comment: *I would like proof that including windows.h will also give me the definition of NULL.* You will not find any such proof, because there is no such proof.  Also you do not need such proof.  If you need a simple, conforming definition of NULL, you should include `<stddef.h>`, as other comments and answers have suggested.  There is no reason not to include this header.  It contains definitions only; it doesn't contain declarations of any library functions you might not want.

Comment: @iloveclang It's less and less obvious what you're trying to accomplish here.  Although it was a strange question (it was never clear why you "didn't want to" use standard headers), you got your answer, and some nice explanations.  Your recent edits seem pointless and argumentative, and the "question" as it now stands is meaningless.  I think I'll have to vote to delete it (since it's currently of no use to future readers), or revert it to one of its former forms, that actually matches the answers you got.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NULL` is defined in the standard C header `stddef.h`, period.

If you run for example gcc/mingw port in Windows, you can just tell any half-decent IDE to find the declaration of `NULL` and end up in `stddef.h` where it says `#define NULL ((void *)0)`.

You can also create a source file like this:

```
// main.c
#include <windows.h>
int main (void)
{}
```

Then compile with `gcc main.c -H`. This will expand all header dependencies, so you'll see which header that includes what other headers. You'll get a whole flood of them and you'll notice that `stddef.h` is indirectly included at some 2-3 different locations.

Conclusion: `NULL` is *not* defined by windows.h or any other windows-specific header that you should be including directly.

If you need to use `NULL`, then the correct approach is to `#include <stddef.h>` regardless of OS.

Comment: well I know that you are wrong because @ikegami made an answer that he deleted, which shows that Minwindef.h at least makes its own definitions based on some stuff. So saying that no windows header ever defines NULL is wrong.

Comment: @iloveclang Ok yes there's some slop in Minwindef.h which may define NULL but only if some `#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION (WINAPI_PARTITION_APP)` is true and NULL isn't already defined. By examining the preprocessor output, you can see that the definition of NULL isn't from Minwindef.h but from stddef.h, assuming you included windows.h. But this is all compiler internals and not something we should worry our pretty heads about. NULL isn't defined there for the purpose of having the application programmer assuming that's the header to include, but for some internal compatibility reasons.

Comment: @iloveclang no, you are wrong. C programs and headers assume that the programmer is not allergic to standard headers

Comment: @ikegami The IDE I used (Codeblocks) pointed out the definition actually used in stddef.h. I also expanded all headers as described in the answer and examined the (vast) preprocessor output. The bulk of minwindef.h was not used and simply removed during preprocessing.